# Using iCloud enabled Core Data NSArray-taking method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, icloud

I've been setting up and testing Core Data in my app and everything works great locally; however, as soon as I enable iCloud via:

```
NSDictionary *options;
    if ([self iCloudEnabled]) {
        options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"},
                    NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : @"iCloudStore"};
        [self subscribeToNotifications];
    } else
        options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"}};
```

And run my app, I get the following error spammed in the console:

```
*** ERROR: this process has called an NSArray-taking method, such as initWithArray:, and passed in an NSSet object.  This is being worked-around for now, but will soon cause you grief.
```

When that error is done printing, everything seems to work normally.

The only other related questions I could find were [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F15337424%2Fordered-relationships-in-sqlite-based-core-data-in-icloud&ei=-8XSVOXgE6nbsASdi4DoDg&usg=AFQjCNHAzBKLyEXYQK0itYKgn1SRKe3nhA&sig2=ZBVzdjwKSlwYydnCUOMqUg) and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F25528019%2Fcore-data-relation-between-objects&ei=-8XSVOXgE6nbsASdi4DoDg&usg=AFQjCNE_unN7JH0jVJcoq7CSm1bFLA-PaQ&sig2=GYXrEr5vj1-qW2nkBJRHkQ), and neither of them were helpful.

I can't even find anywhere that says what that error means.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: From what I've found it's happening after my managedObjectContext is initialized and before the "Using local storage: 0" is printed to the console. Problem is, I have no idea what's being executed in that time (because I'm not calling anything); it seems to be in a background thread.

EDIT2: I should also mention that this only happens the first time the app is launched (on the iCloud "one-time" setup).

EDIT3: Here's the code that initializes my context:

```
- (NSURL *)coreDataLocalURL {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
    NSURL *result = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

    result = [result URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TheAnglersLog"];

    NSError *e;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:result.path])
        // create TheAnglersLog directory if it doesn't exist
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:result.path
                                  withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                   attributes:nil
                                                        error:&e];

    return result;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil)
        return _managedObjectModel;

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TheAnglersLog" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Create the coordinator and store

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self coreDataLocalURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TheAnglersLog.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";

    NSDictionary *options;
    if ([self iCloudEnabled]) {
        options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"},
                    NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : @"TheAnglersLogCloudStore"};
        [self subscribeToNotifications];
    } else
        options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"}};

    NSLog(@"Is iCloud enabled? %@", [self iCloudEnabled] ? @"YES" : @"NO");

    NSPersistentStore *store;

    if (!(store = [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])) {
        // Report any errors we got.
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];

        NSLog(@"Error in persistentStoreCoordinator: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    NSLog(@"Core Data URL: %@", [store URL]);

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same ominous warning in my program as well.  I'm using iCloud with my core data.  My managed object subclass has a one to many relationship with another entity, and its declared as an NSOrderedSet.  When ubiquitous changes are pushed, I get that warning.  I'll post an answer if I can make it go away without turning off iCloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you precisely the problem: Somewhere (not in the code you posted), you're passing an `NSSet` to something which expects an `NSArray`. `NSArray` is ordered and duplicate-inclusive, `NSSet` is unordered and duplicate-exclusive. It converted it to a set for you so it wouldn't crash, but is complaining it may not continue to do so in the future.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but couldn't find anything.  I'll look again, though.  Also, why would this only appear if iCloud is enabled when I initialize my persistent store?

Comment: I'm not modifying any data at all. This happens upon app launch.  Normally I would load the saved data, but at this point there is no saved data. This happens right after I initialize my managedObjectContext.

Comment: What does the code which initializes your context look like?

Comment: Added it to the first post, but it's basically the default core data stack provided by Xcode.  Removing NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey in the addPersistentStore options fixes the issue, but doesn't allow me to use iCloud.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with this.  I'm noticing the error is sent during the iCloud ubiquitous container updates.

Comment: I figured out the issue and have posted my answer to my own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932892/error-this-process-has-called-an-nsarray-taking-method-when-icloud-pushes/30089022#30089022